# Use recursion to make an indented list from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, tree

I'm fairly new to recursion and programming in general and as a beginner exercise I'm trying to take data from a multi-dimensional array and make a simple indented tree out of it.

Let's say I have an array that has arrays nested in it and each 0-index string is a header or as the array goes on, a sub-header of another etc.

```
arr = ['Navigation','Homepage',['Social','Facebook','Twitter'],'Projects','Experience',['Gaming','Steam',['Streaming','Twitch','Hitbox']]];
```

In this case Navigation is the main header of everything and Social is the header for Facebook and Twitter. Projects and Experiences are just children of their header and should have the same indention as Social.

This is the code I came up with:

```
function tree(tarr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < tarr.length; i++) {
      if (typeof tarr[i] == 'string') {
        if (i == 0) {
          console.log(tarr[i] + ":");
        } else {
          console.log(tarr[i]);
        }
      } else {
        tree(tarr[i]);
      }
    }
  }

tree(arr);
```

I think recursion is crucial here and thus I used it. Also, I was able to add colons to the headers but I cannot find a way to indent each subheader and their children the corresponding amount.

Anyways, I am trying to achieve this structure:

```
Navigation:
   Homepage
   Social:
      Facebook
      Twitter
   Projects
   Experiment
   Games:
      Steam
      Streaming:
         Twitch
         Hitbox
```

Comment: Add another argument to the function, something like `depth`, and use that to pad some spaces on the left of the string. Each time you recurse, just pass `depth+1` as the new arg

Comment: @Brennan I have tried that but the depth will just end up being something really high at the end; I need a way to kind of reset it. Otherwise Homepage's depth will be zero and Projects' something else.

Comment: You can always reset it by passing 0 or any other value as the depth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
arr = ['Navigation', 'Homepage', ['Social', 'Facebook', 'Twitter'], 'Projects', 'Experience', ['Gaming', 'Steam', ['Streaming', 'Twitch', 'Hitbox']]];

function print_format(a, intent) {

  a.map((val, index) => {
    if (Array.isArray(val)) {
      print_format(val, intent + 4)
    } else {
      if (index === 0) {
        console.log(" ".repeat(intent) + val + ":")
      } else {
        // Make sure to use same constant value(4), which is used to increment intent
        console.log(" ".repeat(intent + 4) + val)
      }
    }
  })
}

print_format(arr, 0)
```

Comment: Wow, that is a really nice approach. I can really see the power of the latest and greatest Javascript! Thanks.

Comment: I am going to even though this is really beyond my skills. However, it is a nice piece of code to help me learn more! Edit: now that I read your comment about the extra value(4), I understood it, appreciate thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure is weird yet from what i have understood from it, you might come up with a recursive function to handle it as follows;

```js
var arr = ['Navigation','Homepage',['Social','Facebook','Twitter'],'Projects','Experience',['Gaming','Steam',['Streaming','Twitch','Hitbox']]],
makeObj = a => a.reduce((r,p,i) => a.length ? i ? Array.isArray(p) ? (r[a[0]] = Object.assign(r[a[0]], makeObj(p)), r)
                                                                   : (r[a[0]] = Object.assign(r[a[0]], {[p]:null}), r)
                                                : (r[a[0]] = {}, r)
                                            : r, {});
console.log(makeObj(arr));
```